# How to get camera buffer on Linux?

Tags: linux, camera, multimedia

In iOS , I can get camera buffer image from the SDK, but in the Linux world, if I plug a camera to the machine, how can I get the camera buffer in Linux system? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each device in Linux word is linked to a  file into the /dev directory. Precisely, the video devices usually are located into the */dev/v4l* folder. In the folder you should find  symbolic links that point to the */dev/video0* (the real file associated with the physical device file).

If you need to access to the buffer of the cam, you just need to open the file and start reading.